# What is 冎's history and its relation to 骨 and 剮?

Tags: characters, glyph-origin

I am currently studying the character 冎 and I found two interesting facts about it ([reference](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%86%8E)):

- It is the pictographic protoform of 骨
- It is an ancient form of 剮

So from the facts above, I made a chronological summary of the history of 冎, 骨, and 剮 below:

- 冎's original meaning was "bone"
- It was then borrowed to express the meaning "to cut flesh off from bone; lingchi"
- Because of the above reason, a new character i.e. 骨 was created to carry the original meaning "bone"
- Somehow (I am not sure) people felt that a new character was necessary to express "to cut flesh off from bone; lingchi", so they created 剮
- Nowadays people prefer using 剮 but 冎 is still sometimes used as an alternative form

Because I am still a beginner Chinese learner, I am not sure if any point I made above is correct. So I would like to hear your feedback. Thank you very much :-)

Comment: I believe you have the right idea, which is probably why you're not getting any actual answers. The only thing I'd say is that I can't find any actual usage of 冎 to represent the word **guǎ** (*cut flesh off from bone; lingchi*); this seems to be taken from the [*Shuowen*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuowen_Jiezi) definition without corresponding excavated or received text examples.

Comment: @dROOOze I see! Thank you very much for your foodback! :D